# Salvar campos checkbox que são exibidos através de um WHILE com PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tenho uma tabela que se chama **tarefas_check**, quando há registro nessa tabela, o registro é exibido dessa forma:

```
<!-- Checklist -->
<form method="post" action="">
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tarefas_check WHERE ID_tarefas = '$ID_tarefas'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
 
// Os registros são exibidos como checkboxs...
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" <?php if($cont['status']=="1"){ echo "checked";}?>/>
<label><?php echo $cont['texto']; ?></label><br>

<?php } // End while ?>

<!-- Button salvar checklist -->
<button type="submit" name="salvar_check" class="btn-success">Salvar checklists</button>
</form>
```

***A ideia é a seguinte:*** Quando eu selecionar um checkbox e salvar, quero dar um `UPDATE` no campo status dessa mesma tabela, mas somente no `checkbox` selecionado...

O problema é que quando eu seleciono algum e salvo, o `UPDATE` está sendo em  todos os registros, por que está acontecendo isso?

**Código do UPDATE:**

```
<?php 
// Multiplo insert de checkbox
if(isset($_POST['salvar_check'])){ 
   $checkbox = $_POST['status'];
   $result = count($checkbox);

for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++) {  
  $query="UPDATE tarefas_check SET status = 1 WHERE ID_tarefas = '$ID_tarefas'";  
  mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Não foi possível armazenar no banco");
};
```

> Agradeço a qualquer tipo de ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola,

Tente fazer modificar um pouco para enviar o ID de cada tarefa:

1. Ao gerar os checkboxes

```
    ...
    while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
    // Os registros são exibidos como checkboxs...
    // Repare abaixo que a variavel $idTarefa deve vir do banco de dados, igual 'status' e o 'texto'
    <input type="checkbox" name="status[<?=$idTarefa?>]"
    <?php if($cont['status']=="1"){ echo "checked";}?>/>
    <label><?php echo $cont['texto']; ?></label><br>
    <?php } // End while ?>
    ...
```

2. na hora de processar:

```
    ...
    //aqui abaixo, passe por todos os resultados do POST e em cada iteração
    // inicialize a variável $id com o id que veio do HTML no name do checkbox
    foreach ($checkbox as $id => $c){
        $query="UPDATE tarefas_check SET status = 1 WHERE ID_tarefas = '$id'";
        mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Não foi possível armazenar no banco");
    };
    ...
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou! +1 . Como eu faria caso quisesse desmarcar? E voltar o `UPDATE` do status para 0?

Comment: Nesse caso, você teria que criar uma estrategia diferente. Como o formulário HTML só envia os checkboxes que estão marcados, você teria que passar por todos e desmarcar os que não estivessem presentes. Você pode fazer um laço for, e colocar todos os IDs que vieram num string, separados por virgula e usar um sql parecido com esse:

UPDATE tarefas_check SET status = 0 WHERE ID_tarefas NOT IN (1,2,3,4)

Nesse caso, as tarefas 1, 2, 3 e 4 irão voltar a zero e o restante ficar como estão (ou 0, ou 1)

Comment: Me mande um email que te explico melhor: manalista at gmail dot com

Comment: Olá marcos, creio que você digitou o seu email errado. Eu tentei colocar os ID selecionados em uma array e separar com virgula como você falou, fiz dessa forma: `$checks_selecionados = array($id);
    echo implode(',',$checks_selecionados);`, os IDs selecionados são exibidos, mas não separados por virgula... (coloquei essas 2 linhas dentro do `foreach`)

Comment: Olá... O email está certo, só trocar at por @ e dot por . | Sobre colocar os ids no array, crie-o fora do for assim: $selecionados = array(), e use-o dentro do for assim: $selecionados[] = $id. Observe que na inicialização você chama a função array() e na atribuição você não informa a posicação, com os colchetes [], isso significa que é dentro do mesmo array, na proxima posição.